# dry canning, had a little water vapor

Tags: canning, dry

Today was my first go at dry canning. I canned a few jars of dried pinto beans today. I had them in the oven for two hours at 220°F, and the jars were definitely dry beforehand. After getting the lids on and hearing the ping, I noticed a little moisture on the inside of the jars. It's gone now. Is that normal, to see a little water vapor?

Comment: What do you mean by "dry canning"? There are currently no approved methods of oven canning.

Comment: @rumtscho, I used these directions: https://youtu.be/aiSxDNzMwSs